# Xubuntu 14.04LTS - Software Updates - Hash Sum Mismatch

Tags: apt, package-management

During the past week, I am having problems with "hash sum mismatch".  I keep getting hash sum mismatch regardless of the update source/server used.  This is involving the following:

```
W: Failed to fetch ... //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch ... //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/partner/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch ... //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch ... //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

There is a notice about checking the Internet connection.  It doesn't matter which update server I used.  I get the same results.

I have cleared out the `var/lib/apt/lists` and run `apt-get update` in the terminal but no change.  I have also a `dir/file` of `/var/lib/apt/lists.old`.  Do I or can I delete/remove this `dir/file`?

How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you cleared out the `var/lib/apt/lists`. I mean which command did you run?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the data doesn't match the checksum. This could be because you requested it at the exact wrong time, but it could also mean network errors. I have seen this many time and just waiting a few minutes and trying again usually works just fine.

Comment: I used Terminal (sudo su) to "rm" the partial file/directory and the "lists" file/directory.  Still getting "Failed to download repository information -- Check the Internet connection".   I have tried different update servers to no avail.